# Docusign SDK C# Radio Button Group ,Docusign The RecipientId specified in the tab element does not refer to a recipient of this envelope

Tags: c#, sdk, docusignapi, radio-group

I am getting this Issue on Docusign Radio group.I am

**Docusign The RecipientId specified in the tab element does not refer to a recipient of this envelope. Tab refers to RecipientId 88183597-41B3-42C5-9E48-D1A4D5C3F262 who is not present.**

**This Works Fine:**

```
return new RadioGroup
            {
                GroupName= Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
                DocumentId = documentId, 
                RecipientId = userId,
             
            };
```

**This doesn't work .**

```
return new RadioGroup
            {
                GroupName= Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
                DocumentId = documentId, 
                RecipientId = userId,
               Radios= new List<Radio>()
               {
                   new Radio(){ PageNumber="1",Selected = "true",Value ="X",XPosition = "300", YPosition = "75" } ,
                  // new Radio(){ PageNumber="1",Selected = "false",Value ="Y",XPosition = "350", YPosition = "75" }
               },
            };
```

I am setting Signer Tabs as

```
 signer.Tabs = new Tabs
            {
                SignHereTabs = signers,
                InitialHereTabs = initialsHere,
                DateSignedTabs = dateSinged,
                ApproveTabs = approves,
                DeclineTabs = declines,
                FullNameTabs = fullNames,
                CheckboxTabs = checkBoxes,
                RadioGroupTabs = radiobuttongroups,
                TextTabs = textboxes,

            };
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After Long debugging came to know that DocuSign converts Recipient Ids to lower case and somehow it was not matching TAB's Recipient ID, Had to convert Recipient IDs of signer and tabs  to lower.